# Protracto with C#r: non-angular login page is reloading

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, protractor, specflow

I have a question that is related to the the C#+specflow+protractor rather than jasmine

The log in process is the following

Navigate to home page & enter credentials [Non-angular]
Wait for sometime and navigate to the angular page

Whenever I try to execute the code I get the below error.

-> Using app.config
Given launch the browser https://dev-erou.../#/
executed test
-> done: PageTestSteps.GivenLaunchTheBrowser(" https://dev-erou...") 
And in the login screen enter credentails username,password
-> error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Then click on login button
-> skipped because of previous errors
Then select the eroutes option
-> skipped because of previous errors
Then click on proceed button
-> skipped because of previous errors

```
[Given(@"launch the browser(.*)")]
    public void GivenLaunchTheBrowserHttpsDev_Eroutes_Cat_Com(String URL)
    {
        //driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\dontuak\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32");
        //var options = new ChromeOptions();
        //driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        //IWebDriver ngDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
        //ngDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);

        NgWebDriver ngDriver = new NgWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());
        ngDriver.IgnoreSynchronization = true;
        ngDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
        ngDriver.IgnoreSynchronization = false;
        Console.WriteLine("executed test");


    }

    [Given(@"in the login screen enter credentails(.*),(.*)")]
    public void GivenInTheLoginScreenEnterCredentails(string username, string pwd)
    {
        ngDriver.IgnoreSynchronization = true;
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("cwsUID")).SendKeys(username);
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("cwsPwd")).SendKeys(pwd);


    }

    [Then(@"click on login button")]
    public void ThenClickOnLoginButton()
    {
        ngDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='Submitbtn']")).Click();


    }

    [Then(@"select the eroutes option")]
    public void ThenSelectTheEroutesOption()
    {

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);

            ngDriver.FindElement(NgBy.Binding("caret-group")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(NgByBinding.ClassName("group-dropdown")).Click();
            //driver.FindElement(NgByBinding.ClassName("[object Object]")).Click();

}

    [Then(@"click on proceed button")]
    public void ThenClickOnProceedButton()
    {
        driver.FindElement(NgByBinding.ClassName("proceed-button")).Click();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like that you didn't copy all code of the class, as fields like (ngDriver or driver) are missing. Could you post the whole code?

Comment: Thanks @AndreasWillich I was able to resolve the issue

Comment: Good to here. Please post an answer how you solved it, so that future people who will find your question, knows what you did and they can fix the issue themselfes. Thanks!

Comment: Please find the cod below which fixed my issue
I created a Base class

Comment: public class Hooks
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;
        public Hooks(IObjectContainer _objectContainer)
        {
            this.objectContainer = _objectContainer;
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(driver);

        }
public class BasePage 

    {
        public IWebDriver driver;
        public NgWebDriver ngdriver;
        public BasePage(IWebDriver _driver)
{
Here I initated the Page factory} which help me to resolve the issue